# What privilege is required to read the unshared private virtual address space of a process externally?

Tags: windows, process

> The virtual address space for a process is the set of virtual memory addresses that it can use. The address space for each process is private and cannot be accessed by other processes **unless it is shared**. - [Windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space)

I'm testing and researching security scanning strategies. If one process (the scanner) wants to read the memory space of another, is administrator privilege (edit: the privilege assigned by the os to processes run in administrator mode) sufficient to override this requirement?

Edit: Apparently `PROCESS_VM_READ` [is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) but [documentation doesn't seem to explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights) under which conditions such a trait is attributed to a process. Apparently, [ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-lists) are involved:

> When you call the OpenProcess function, the system checks the
> requested access rights against the DACL in the process's security
> descriptor. When you call the GetCurrentProcess function, the system
> returns a pseudohandle with the maximum access that the DACL allows to
> the caller

but from all this documentation I'm only more confused than when I began.

Comment: There is no such thing as an *"administrator privilege"*.

Comment: Like it says in the documentation of ReadProcessMemory: [The handle must have PROCESS_VM_READ access to the process.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory)

Comment: @RaymondChen But that same documentation neglects to explain nor link to any other pages explain what determines whether a process can get `PROCESS_VM_READ`. Even [the documentation page that lists that trait](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights) doesn't seem to say a single thing about how that is achieved. Nor does that or your comment answer whether or not a process running "as administrator" in windows (or some other condition other than just being in kernel mode) gets such access. Presumably it is the case since AVs are a thing.

Comment: Just like with any other security access mask, whether you can obtain `PROCESS_VM_READ` depends on the ACL on the object you are trying to get it from. If the ACL says that you can access it, then you get access. Otherwise you don't. Each process can customize its ACL to block or allow access to whoever it likes.

Comment: @RaymondChen interesting so do antivirus and other host-based defense systems not rely on any memory scan based monitoring? I was certain such a thing was customary.

Comment: Anti-malware software has kernel-mode components, and kernel mode can bypass all permissions.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah. I knew drivers were used for rootkit scanning, but didn't realize the kernel mode code was used for scanning user-land programs.